# Generate Extension Methods using System.CodeDom

Tags: c#, extension-methods, codedom, system-codedom-compiler

Has anyone ever tried to generate extension methods using System.CodeDom under .NET 4.0? There doesn't seem to be any way to specify a CodeMemberMethod or CodeParameterDeclarationExpression as being an extension method/parameter.

If this isn't possible, are there any good workarounds?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently CodeDom isn't able to generate the correct code for the first parameter of an extension method, but you can cheat it like this:

```
var param = new CodeParameterDeclarationExpression("this string", "s");
```

It will blissfully ignore the fact that "this string" is not a valid type...

Comment: This actually fits my needs ridiculously well. I am using extension methods for syntactic reasons, nothing more, so no members on the "this" parameter will ever be accessed, so I don't even have to worry about any type checking in System.CodeDom... Thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0):

See [Extension Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.extensionattributeSee%20%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Quote:

> In Visual Basic, you should use this attribute to create an extension method. For more information, see Extension Methods (Visual Basic).
>
> In C#, you do not need to use this attribute; you should use the this (C# Reference) modifier for the first parameter to create an extension method. The compiler automatically emits ExtensionAttribute for extension methods. For more information, see Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide).
>
> If you are writing a compiler that supports extension methods, your compiler should emit this attribute on each extension method and on each class and assembly that contains one or more extension methods.

Comment: It will just apply the ExtensionAttribute to the method, which is an error in C#... the compiler says to use the `this` modifier instead

Comment: Are you trying to use the compiler, or reflection emit? I may have misunderstood your question, if you are referring to some kind of in-IDE script/addin; That said, you might be consider using [Compiler As A Service](http://weblogs.asp.net/britchie/archive/2010/08/08/c-compiler-as-a-service.aspx), anyway

Comment: I am using System.CodeDom, which is a library included in the standard .NET framework for generating code files (or assemblies).