# Creating extension method using CodeDOM

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods, codedom

I'm trying to create an extension method using CodeDOM. There doesn't seem to be any support for them and using `ExtensionAttribute` (which C# uses internally to mark extension methods) is not allowed.

It's possible to use [a trick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6011269/41071) to specify the `this` modifier, but how do I make the containing class `static`, so that the code actually compiles?

Since `static` is a C# concept, it's not exposed through the CodeDOM API. And setting `TypeAttributes` to `TypeAttributes.Abstract | TypeAttributes.Sealed | TypeAttributes.Public` doesn't work, because

> an abstract class cannot be sealed or static

How do I make the extension method to compile?

Comment: Future readers: I think the solid solution is now [tag:Roslyn], and adding a static modifier to the class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're looking for:

```
var staticClass = new CodeTypeDeclaration("Extensions")
    {
        Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public|MemberAttributes.Static
    };
```

However, this appears not to work. Interestingly enough:

```
provider.Supports(GeneratorSupport.StaticConstructors);
// True

provider.Supports(GeneratorSupport.PublicStaticMembers);
// True
```

But yet when you go and output it, no changes even though the Attributes property clearly changes from `0x00005002` to `0x00006003`.

[Per Microsoft Connect this is not possible](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/526505/microsoft-csharp-csharpcodegenerator-outputtypeattributes-does-not-write-static-class-when-codetypedefinition-has-typeattributes-abstract-typeattributes-sealed):

> Thanks for reporting this. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like we can support static classes for CodeDom.
>
> The reason is that one of the design goals of CodeDom is to be language-independent, so that any code generated for one language can easily be generated for a different language. While static classes are used often in C#, VB does not support them. Therefore, adding support for static classes will mean that some code that can compile for C# won't be compilable for VB, which goes against our goals.
>
> While we can't act on this issue, we ask that you please continue to provide feedback in the future to help us improve.

---

A dirty workaround:

```
var type = new CodeTypeDeclaration("Extensions");
type.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public;
type.StartDirectives.Add(
    new CodeRegionDirective(CodeRegionMode.Start, "\nstatic"));
type.EndDirectives.Add(
    new CodeRegionDirective(CodeRegionMode.End, String.Empty));
```

Produces:

```
#region
static
public class Extensions
{
}
#endregion
```

Which compiles.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything. And using `MemberAttributes.Private` doesn't change the class to private either.

Comment: @svick: weird, I've confirmed this is the case with 4.0. Checking with older versions of the compiler.

Comment: @svick: Updated to include a workaround using `CodeRegionDirective`s.

Comment: I think I like my workaround better. If I have two bad solutions and one of them is “a clever trick”, I'd rather go with the more obvious one.

Comment: @svick: agreed. Although you could always place my trick in an extension method (oh the irony) to make it more visible. Either way, what an aggravating find.

Comment: This hack breaks down when attributes have to be placed on the static class.  In my case, I had to disable generation of GeneratedCodeAttribute.  Thanks for a nice hack though!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of compiling the `CodeCompileUnit` directly, you could get the source code, replace `class Extensions` with `static class Extensions` and compile that code.

Comment: Note that I don't like this solution and that I am still looking for a better one.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include why you'll have to go this route. I've included the MS Connect article detailing the same.

Comment: I wonder how will insert that into a namespace as a type since it's a `CodeSnippetTypeMember`

Answer (score 2):

Cleaned up the hack provided by sixlettervariables a little: placed it into a static method, as mentioned in the discussion.

```
public static void MarkAsStaticClassWithExtensionMethods(this CodeTypeDeclaration class_)
{
   class_.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public;

   class_.StartDirectives.Add(new CodeRegionDirective(
           CodeRegionMode.Start, Environment.NewLine + "\tstatic"));

   class_.EndDirectives.Add(new CodeRegionDirective(
           CodeRegionMode.End, string.Empty));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your code to compile exactly how your want it by converting it directly into a string, and then hacking it:

```cs
    private static CodeSnippetTypeMember CreateStaticClass(CodeTypeDeclaration type)
    {
        var provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
        using (var sourceWriter = new StringWriter())
        using (var tabbedWriter = new IndentedTextWriter(sourceWriter, "\t"))
        {
            tabbedWriter.Indent = 2;
            provider.GenerateCodeFromType(type, tabbedWriter, new CodeGeneratorOptions()
            {
                BracingStyle = "C",
                IndentString = "\t"
            });
            return new CodeSnippetTypeMember("\t\t" + sourceWriter.ToString().Replace("public class", "public static class"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I suggested in [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6308622/41071).